# how to remove the html tags from the sql database using laravel?I have used {!! description !!}

Tags: database, laravel, tags

[image]**there is no data. but it is showing the tags.I want to make it null**

there is no data. but it is showing the tags.I want to make it null

Comment: If you want to get rid of all tags you can use `strip_tags` php function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: my view file is okay. but inside database it is showing the tags.any way to get rid of them

Comment: You can use strip_tags to get rid of tags while storing in database. For existing records you can fetch all records run them through strip_tags and then persist them back to database

Comment: However keep in mind that if you have some html snippet kind of data in database which you are using in a view with {!! $data !!} then you should keep the data with html tags in the database

Comment: i am using if- else condition. when i dont insert any data it will show a default data.but the database is not null because of the tags.thats why no data is showing.any suggestion?

Comment: For existing records you can fetch all records run them through strip_tags and then persist them back to database

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I have solved with the following:

When your textarea have some spaces and uses some wysiwyg editors, we can get something like after inserting into database.

There are two kind of thinking:

1. We can strip tags when there is only tags and no items.
2. We also have to remove spaces if there are some spaces typed by mistake.

To solve upper list.

1. First, check the length of the document when tags are removed.

```
    if(strip_tags($body)=="") null:$body;
```

This condition is solved the first thing in our wishlist. It will save null when there is no content. It will save all the tags if there are some text including spaces.

However, How should we check if there is only spaces?

We have to strip the spaces and check the length of tag removed string.

So at last,

```
$body = (str_replace('&nbsp;', '', strip_tags($request->body))==null)? null: $body;
```

### Result

[image: Final Result comparison]

I have to set string null instead of null because I configured my database not to allow null in my case. I hope it will solve the problem.